# What is the "underlying code" of a Python `with` statement?

Tags: python

Suppose you have:

```
with with_target_expression() as with_variable:
    with_block_contents(with_variable)
```

I understand the basic high-level intent here - that the target / `with_variable` will be "gotten rid of" sensibly after the `with_block_contents` completes.

But what is the full "raw" / "basic" Python being called/implied by this?

Comment: No, this isn't an attempt to solve some hacky problem by mucking around with the implementation. I just want to be certain I've fully understood what it's doing.

Comment: It's open source, why not study it? That code looks like from the documentation, which part there is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

An answer is this:

```
with_target = with_target_expression()
with_variable = with_target.__enter__()
exception_raised = False

try:
    with_block_contents(with_variable)

except Exception:
    exception_raised = True
    exception_details = sys.exc_info()
    should_suppress = with_target.__exit__(*exception_details)
    if(not should_suppress):
        raise

finally:
    if(not exception_raised):
        with_target.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

But the canonical answer can be found in the [documentation for the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) (which will be updated into the future)

The above code is nearly equivalent (but differently laid out) to what's in that link.

Comment: More definitively, a pure-Python translation is provided in [the documentation for the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: (There are some subtle differences between it and your answer, most of which handle obscure corner cases that nonetheless need to be handled to define the semantics precisely.)

Comment: @chepner that (your link) is definitely something I'd accept if you wanted to post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm fine with it being edited into your answer.

Comment: More importantly than the corner cases is that the `with` documentation, unlike the old "what's new" page, will be updated to incorporate changes (as it was in Python 3.10 to support parentheses around multiple context managers) to the syntax or semantics.